# EC2 Curl to server running on itself

Tags: curl, amazon-ec2, cron

I have a cron job defined on an Amazon Linux EC2 instance. The cron job runs a curl command to a server running on the same EC2 instance. It is supposed to execute every 15 minutes.

```
*/15 * * * * curl http://ec2-54-221-195-78.compute-1.amazonaws.com/twitter/refresh
```

http://ec2-54-221-195-78.compute-1.amazonaws.com/twitter/refresh doesn't seem to be getting called ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out the cron job itself was executing every 15 minutes as expected. The problem was that curl was failing. It was because of the url. When I changed the cron job to following it worked fine.

```
*/15 * * * * curl http://54.221.195.78/twitter/refresh
```

Note that unless you have specifically turned it off, every time the cron job runs it will send an email which in my case was stored in this file /var/spool/mail/ec2-user. You can check the file to see if the cron job is executing and what was the output of the command.

Also note that 54.221.195.78 in my case was an elastic ip asigned to the instance.